# How do I get the name of the test method that was run in a testng tear down method?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testng

Basically, I have a teardown method that I want to log to the console which test was just run. How would I go about getting that string?

I can get the class name, but I want the actual method that was just executed.

```
public class TestSomething {

    @AfterMethod
    public void tearDown() {
        System.out.println("The test that just ran was: " + getTestThatJustRanMethodName());
    }

    @Test
    public void testCase() {
       assertTrue(1 == 1);
    }
}
```

...should output to the screen: "The test that just ran was: testCase"

However, I don't know the magic that `getTestThatJustRanMethodName` should actually be.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Declare a parameter of type ITestResult in your @AfterMethod and TestNG will inject it:

```
@AfterMethod
public void afterMethod(ITestResult result) {
  System.out.println("method name:" + result.getMethod().getMethodName());
}
```

Comment: tks,  and i use 'Reporter.setCurrentTestResult(result);' to change the report stream to test method

Answer (score 35):

If you want to get the method name *before* the test is executed you can use the following:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

@BeforeMethod
public void nameBefore(Method method)
{
    System.out.println("Test name: " + method.getName());       
}
```

Comment: Also works for `@AfterMethod` ... what the OP asked for ;)

Comment: Helped me though ✓

Comment: Didn't work for me org.testng.TestNGException: 
Can inject only one of <ITestContext, XmlTest> into a @AfterClass annotated tearDown.

Answer (score 8):

Just declare a `java.lang.reflect.Method` parameter.

```
 @BeforeMethod
 public void beforeTestMethod(Method testMethod){
    System.out.println("Before Testmethod: " + testMethod.getName());       
 }
```

But TestNG allows you to **[inject](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#dependency-injection)** a lot more ;)

> - Any **@Before** method or **@Test** method can declare a parameter of type **`ITestContext`**.
> - Any **@AfterMethod** method can declare a parameter of type **`ITestResult`**, which will reflect the result of the test method that was just run.
> - Any **@Before** and **@After** methods can declare a parameter of type **`XmlTest`**, which contain the current  tag.
> - Any **@BeforeMethod** (and **@AfterMethod**) can declare a parameter of type **`java.lang.reflect.Method`**. This parameter will receive the test method that will be called once this @BeforeMethod finishes (or after the method as run for @AfterMethod).
> - Any **@BeforeMethod** can declare a parameter of type **`Object[]`**. This parameter will receive the list of parameters that are about to be fed to the upcoming test method, which could be either injected by TestNG, such as **`java.lang.reflect.Method`** or come from a **`@DataProvider`**.
> - Any **@DataProvider** can declare a parameter of type **`ITestContext`** or **`java.lang.reflect.Method`**. The latter parameter will receive the test method that is about to be invoked.

Answer (score 2):

Another (although not as simple as [Cedric's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2954047/1421925)) way that TestNG supports this is to [register a listener](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#testng-listeners):

```
@Listeners({MethodListener.class})
public class ListenerTest {

  @Test
  public void someTest() {
  }

}
```

Where the listener could look like this:

```
public class MethodListener implements IInvokedMethodListener {

  @Override
  public void beforeInvocation(IInvokedMethod method, ITestResult testResult) {

  }

  @Override
  public void afterInvocation(IInvokedMethod method, ITestResult testResult) {
    System.out.println(method.getTestMethod().getMethodName());
  }
}
```

This particular listener would print the method name (i.e. `someTest`) to the console. It would be executed after *every* executed test.

If you are generating the testSuite programmatically then you can add the listener as follows instead of adding `@Listeners({MethodListener.class})` over each test class

```
    List<String> listeners = new ArrayList<String>();
    listeners.add(MethodListener.class.getName());
    testSuite.setListeners(listeners);
```

Comment: You can just use testResult.getMethod().getMethodName(). No need to get IInvokedMethod.

Answer (score 1):

In my own project I access this data thanks to a JUnit `@Rule`.

```
String testName;
String className;

@Rule
public TestWatcher watcher = new TestWatcher() {
    public void starting(Description description) {
        testName = description.getMethodName();
        className = description.getClassName();
        logger.info("Starting test " + testName + " in class " + className);
    }
};
```

Comment: This question is about TestNG not JUnit