# How to get the method name?

Tags: java, testng

I'm using `TestNG` with `Selenium`. In that, I'm using `@AfterMethod` and `@Test` annotations.

In the method that I have used `@AfterMethod`, I need the method name which has `@Test`.

For ex:

```
@Test
public void testmethod() {
  System.out.println("test");
}

@AfterMethod
public void aftermethod() {
   String methodnameofTESTANnnoation=....?
    System.out.println(methodnameof@TESTannotation);
}
```

Here for method name of `@TEST` annotation variable, I need the name of `@Test` annotation method i.e **testmethod**.

Comment: is there any problem with returning value? make testmethod public String testmethod() and add return("testmethod") for example then try String methodnameofTESTANnnoation= testmethod();

Comment: @shmosel Question is about testng. For testng check this out - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2952202/how-do-i-get-the-name-of-the-test-method-that-was-run-in-a-testng-tear-down-meth?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @Grasshopper Good catch. Your link looks like a perfect duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TestNG is able to inject `Method` reference into configuration method.
From [the documentation](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#native-dependency-injection):

> Any @BeforeMethod (and @AfterMethod) can declare a parameter of type
>   java.lang.reflect.Method. This parameter will receive the test method
>   that will be called once this @BeforeMethod finishes (or after the
>   method as run for @AfterMethod).

So, with your sample:

```
@Test
public void testmethod(){
  System.out.println("test");
}

@AfterMethod
public void aftermethod(Method m){
  String methodNameOfTest = m.getName();
  System.out.println(methodNameOfTest);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. that's worked...

Comment: @Sandeep Then, accept the answer ;)