# Log4j - Print test case name in log file

Tags: java, log4j

I have a java project which uses log4j as a logger. The requirement is to have the test case name printed in the log file.

There are multiple tests in one class And the project supports parallel execution as well. A logger instance is created for each test.

I used system.Setproprty to associate my current logger instance with a the test case name. Following is my log4j.properties file :-

```
log4j.appender.logFileAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss} [%t] ${testCaseName} %5p (%F:%L) - %m%n
log4j.appender.logFileAppender.Append=false
log4j.appender.logFileAppender.file=./log/UITest.log
```

And the runtime variable ${testCaseName} is set while creating a new instance of logger file as follows :-

```
public Logger log; 
public synchronized Logger initializeLogger(String testName) 
    { 
    log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(testName);      
    System.setProperty("testCaseName", testName);             
    PropertyConfigurator.configure(log4jPropertiesFilePath); 
    return log; 
    }
```

The above looger instance creation method is called in a @BeforeMethod.

Currently the logger file is printing the test name of the last test in a class (In non-parallel ans parallel execution mode)

Kindly help me identify the issue due to which multiple test cases are not having their testcase name printed in the log file.

Comment: I think log file is initialized only once during test case run, so only 1 test name is printed. Did you tried  Java `reflection` parameter `Method` or  `testng` annotation `ITestResult`.  You can check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2952202/how-do-i-get-the-name-of-the-test-method-that-was-run-in-a-testng-tear-down-meth

Comment: Thanks for the reply Amit. But I am calling the "initializeLogger" method before each test. Also when 2 tests in a class are run, my log file has the logs with the name of second test case. I use the ITestResult to pass the testName as parameter to initialize logger, it works fine. The only problem is associating the testCaseName to different logger instances.

Comment: Anyone aware for the solution of this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

try adding this to your test

```
  @Rule 
  public TestName testName = new TestName();

  @Before 
  public void printTestName() {
     System.out.println("Running ==> " + testName.getMethodName()); 
  }
```

Comment: Can you please add some explanation as well along with your code so that it can help Original Poster(OP) of the question properly. Welcome to stackoverflow, please follow https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to set up a thead context variable, and use this variable name in the log4j configuration files.

In the java method level code, save the testName into the thread context "testCaseName".

```
    import org.apache.logging.log4j.ThreadContext;
    
       ThreadContext.put("testCaseName", testName);
```

From the log4j2 config, print the thread context variable by adding this line:
`${ctx:testCaseName}]`

It works for me, good luck.

Comment: The OP is using Log4j 1.x, while this answer uses Log4j2. Can you rewrite it for Log4j 1.x (there is an `MDC` class in Log4j 1.x).